# Where are save games stored on my computer?

Tags: pc, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

I want to transfer my saved game to my other computer, but I can't seem to find where the game puts saves. [Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=stick%20of%20truth%20save%20location) doesn't turn up anything relevant to my problem which figures since it released today.

So, where can I find my save files?

Comment: Would upvote again if I could. Thank you for trying to research the problem before asking a new question!.

Comment: Are you using Steam?

Comment: @peper757 Yes I'm using Steam.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should be able to find your save files here:

`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\South Park - The Stick of Truth\save`

Comment: Or more universally `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\My Games\South Park - The Stock of Truth\save`.

Comment: Yes, very tasty South Park stock

Comment: Thank god, there are 2 config files that kind of did something under program files, but I finally was able to turn off full screen with the user.ini in there